# Splitting numbers and strings repeatedly

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = index ( 1.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00)  _x_ ( error error error ) t ( 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 )
```

I need this to be split into a list as follows:

```
['index', '1.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00', 
'_x_', 'error error error',
't', '1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02']
```

I am unable to come up with a regex for doing this.

Comment: Regex is a tool for matching patterns, here you don't have any pattern - just a string you want to split which is why Regex is not the right tool for the job - use string split.

Comment: `str.split` expects a character or sequence, so you'd have to filter out the parenthesis manually later and deal with possible variations in whitespace before/after them. I think `re` is a good fit.

Comment: @Anand: is your string looks like this: s = "index ...." or s = "s = index (....)"?

Comment: @AlexKotliarov It is s = "index ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list comprehension that does it:

```
[item.strip() for item in s.replace("(", ")").split(")")]
```

Here's some code that basically does what you want.  Almost.

```
mylist = []
for item in s.replace("(", ";").replace(")", ";").split(";"):
    mylist.append(item.strip())

print mylist[:-1]
```

Output:

```
['index', '1.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00', '_x_', 'error error error', 't', '1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02']
```

Comment: This may be slower than the regex solution due to multiple iterations through the string and making several copies along the way

Comment: That's probably true, but it's far easier to understand.

Comment: how about `[item.strip() for item in s.replace("(", ")").split(")")]` instead - one less `str.replace` and forgoes the manual loop in favour of list comprehension

Comment: Very nice!  I like it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following regex to split this string (Very last list's item would be an empty string.):

```
    import re
    s = "index ( 1.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00)  _x_ ( error error error ) t ( 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 ) "
    re.split("\s*?(?:\(|\))\s*", s)
```

This results in:

```
['index', '1.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00', '_x_', 'error error error', 't', '1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02', '']
```

Also, you could use following regex to extract your string's components and then process them  (e.g. strip white space from a substring). This regex assumes that string has balanced left/right parens:

```
re.findall("(?:(?<=\()[^)]*?(?=\))|[a-z_]+)",s)
```

It should produce following output:

```
['index', ' 1.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00', '_x_', ' error error error ', 't', ' 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 1.2500000e+02 ']
```

Comment: @Peter: I have asked OP to clarify how this string should look like. I have assumed that it is s = "index...."

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @AlexKotliarov's answer, but just splitting on whitespace and parens

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[\s()]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['index', '1.0000000e+00', '2.0000000e+00', '3.0000000e+00', '_x_', 'error', 'error', 'error', 't', '1.2500000e+02', '1.2500000e+02', '1.2500000e+02', '']
```

Explaination:

Split on one or more characters `+` in the set `[`..`]`: whitespace `\s` and parenthesis `(` & `)`